# How to bind an event on two html elements

Tags: html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have created a dropdown menu. This menu opens by pointing on a parent div. I want to hide this div when user leaves both, the parent div or dropdown menu

```
$(function(){
$('.a').live('mouseenter',function(){
    $('#dropdown').stop(false, true).hide();

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#dropdown').css({
        position:'absolute',
        top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px',
        right: '115px',
        left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
        zIndex:1000,
        width:'100px'
    });

    $('#dropdown').stop().slideDown(500);

    if($('#dropdown').mouseleave() && $('#'+id).mouseleave()){
        $('#dropdown').slideUp(500);
    }
 });
});
```

​
**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/ThzuL/1/)**

Comment: Are you aware that [`.live()` is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com)? You should be using `.on()` instead (or `.delegate()` if you're stuck on a version of jQuery below 1.7).

Comment: by using `on` the error on console is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' `

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add mouseleave event and check the dropdown, to keep it short, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ThzuL/7/)

i hope this is what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to multiple elements by seperating them with commas in the selector

```
$('.a, .this, .that, div, form').live(....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple selector as @Dale suggested or use same class for both the elements and use

```
$(".commonClass").live(function(){

});
```

If you want to bind same event to more elements you just need to apply `commonClass` to them instead of adding new selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AQweU/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/k986c/

Few things;

- use `.on` event instead of live.
- use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')`.
- not sure about this condition `if($('#dropdown').mouseleave() && $('#'+id).mouseleave()){` see the code below what I have done

please note the demo in the question has Jq 1.7.2 hence the `.on` use.

rest checkout the code: (hope it help the casue) `:)`

```
$(function(){
    $('.a,#dropdown').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $('#dropdown').stop(false, true).hide();

        var id = this.id;
        $('#dropdown').css({
            position:'absolute',
            top: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px',
            right: '115px',
            left: $(this).offset().left + 'px',
            zIndex:1000,
            width:'100px'
        });

        $('#dropdown').stop().slideDown(500);

        $('#dropdown, #'+id).mouseleave(function(){   
            $('#dropdown').slideUp(500);

        });
    });
});
​
```

Comment: by using `on` the error on console is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' `

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k986c/ ? try this @RanaMuhammadUsman I am on chrome - alienware and seems to be working fine

Comment: This usage of `.on()` isn't equivalent to `.live()`. You need something like `$(document).on('mouseenter','a', function(){/**/})`. Also if his jQuery is older than 1.7, `.on()` won't work.

Comment: @nbrooks lol I am totally confused with whats not working I am removing my post! `:)`

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman try this: http://jsfiddle.net/AQweU/ and it seems to be working now `:)` lol < is it >